# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot set the element to 'abc'. Did you interact with the correct element?

Tags: android, ruby, appium, capybara

I am using rspec framework for mobile automation testing. There I use appium_capybara along with appium_lib.

When I am trying to set any value in the text box, it throws an exception:
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: Cannot set the element to ‘abc’. Did you interact with the correct element?

My code is:

```
$capy_driver = Capybara.current_session.driver
$capy_driver.find_custom(:xpath, "//android.widget.ImageView[@text='Email Address']")[0].send_keys 'abc'
```

Here click is working, but when I use send key then it throws exception.

Updating source code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<hierarchy index="0" class="hierarchy" rotation="0" width="768" height="1184">
  <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
    <android.widget.LinearLayout index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
      <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" resource-id="android:id/content" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
        <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
          <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
            <android.widget.FrameLayout index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" text="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="true" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
              <android.view.View index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
                <android.view.View index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
                  <android.view.View index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,0][768,1184]" displayed="true">
                    <android.view.View index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,48][768,1052]" displayed="true">
                      <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[196,48][572,208]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.view.View index="1" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="Login" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[315,296][453,366]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.widget.ImageView index="2" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="Email Address" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[86,410][682,506]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.widget.ImageView index="3" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="Password" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="true" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[86,550][682,646]" displayed="true">
                        <android.widget.ImageView index="0" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.ImageView" text="" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[582,550][682,646]" displayed="true" />
                      </android.widget.ImageView>
                      <android.widget.Button index="4" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.widget.Button" text="Login" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[208,702][586,798]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.view.View index="5" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="No account? " resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[196,868][364,906]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.view.View index="6" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="Create Account" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[364,868][572,906]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.view.View index="7" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="Privacy" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[222,970][300,1000]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.view.View index="8" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="Terms &amp; Conditions" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[336,970][546,1000]" displayed="true" />
                      <android.view.View index="9" package="com.pgk.auto.android" class="android.view.View" text="Powered by PGK Auto" resource-id="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[216,1020][552,1052]" displayed="true" />
                    </android.view.View>
                  </android.view.View>
                </android.view.View>
              </android.view.View>
            </android.widget.FrameLayout>
          </android.widget.FrameLayout>
        </android.widget.FrameLayout>
      </android.widget.FrameLayout>
    </android.widget.LinearLayout>
  </android.widget.FrameLayout>
</hierarchy>
```

Comment: The error is explaining what the issue is - You're trying to set the value on an element that doesn't have a value to set. Look inside that element and find the correct element that can actually have a value set on it

Comment: @ThomasWalpole... Yes this is the issue.Both email and password control are the android.widget.ImageView control. I am attaching my source code for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, any help will be appreciated...Thanks